# Method to insert text in empty spots of a subplot

Tags: python, subplot

Im trying to insert text in a subplot that is centered or structured around the subplot spot i want it to, but I cant really find a good way how.

I have a 4x4 subplot, where not all "spots" have a plot included. Currently the subplot looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCCEb.jpg .
You can see the "test" strings, but the problem is they all try to get as close as possible to a point within their spot, which makes sense since I only specified 1 absolute pair of absolute coordinates. How to make easy relative coordinates to the subplot spot is what im struggling with.
Thats what I tried for now (I try to include only the relevant code):

```
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(4,4, sharex='col', sharey='row', figsize= 
    (20,20))
    fig.tight_layout()

    for i in range(0,3)
            for j in range(i+1,4)
              axes[i,j].scatter(X,Y, s = 10)
              axes[i,j].plot(X,X*lin.coef_, 'r')
              axes[i,j].plot(X, Y_p, color = 'g')
              axes[j,i].axis("off")
              axes[j,i].text(0.5,0.5,s= "test" , fontsize = 15, ha =                                                       
              "center", va = "center")
```

How can I replace the '0.5' in the last line with better references to the i and j coordinates of the subplot?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. What I needed was this argument `transform = axes[j,i].transAxes`
so it looks like this:

```
    axes[j,i].text(0.5,0.5,s= "test" , fontsize = 15, ha =                                                       
    "center", va = "center", transform=axes[j,i].transAxes)
```